# Signing app for Sideloading

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, digital-certificate, sideloading

I want to be clear with a question about Sideloading applications for Windows 8 (for use within the company.) Read some articles about it, always write the application before deployment must be cryptographically signed (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx). I found how to sign my app (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/hh446592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but there was a question where to get the key for signature applications. It can be purchased from Verisign, Comodo or a another? If so, what will it take, how much time it takes? Do I understand correctly that the App Packager is not needed for signing app, because the app package generated a Visual Studio, after that you must use CertMgr install the certificate to the domain and sign this certificate application with SignTool? If I'm wrong - please correct me, please

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to generate certificate using `Active Directory Certificate Services`.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/01/03/walkthrough-request-a-digital-certificate-from-certificate-server-or-create-a-testing-digital-certificate-to-sign-a-package.aspx) is a quick walkthrough on how to generate certificate from AD CS

[Active Directory Certificate Services Step-by-Step Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772393%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this without access to AD CS, you may purchase a code signing certificate from any Certificate Authority that offers a RFC3161 timestamping service. The time it takes to get a code signing certificate varies based on how long it takes the certificate authority to verify you are who you say you are.

You will need to manually timestamp the appx file, however, as VS2013 doesn't support using a third party CA's timestamping service when generating appx files. You need to timestamp the appx because otherwise the software will expire the date your code signing certificate expires.

This is how I use the signtool:

```
signtool sign /fd SHA256 /a /f YourCertKey.pfx /p mypassword /tr http://timestampserver.yourca.com/somepath YourApp.appx
```

Here is more information on using signtool to sign app packages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835835(v=vs.85).aspx

If you're attempting to sideload these appx files, you may also need to enable sideload privileges on the computers in question. If you aren't using a domain-joined Windows Enterprise on the client computers, this may involve purchasing side load licenses from Microsoft volume licensing or a partner.

Here is more information about sideloading: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/jj874388.aspx